# How would I return a <link href="" /> href with jquery, ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a chrome extension and I need to know how I can use `var` or some other way to get the `href` of a `< link>` tag on the website the source code has `< link href="//api-cdn.github.io/stylesheetfile.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
and I want it to take the `href` value and replace where it says in my code below **Insert the stylesheet href link here** its near the end of my code well I want the script to take the `href` value from the html file on the website and automatically place the `href` in that spot when my extension is run. How would I do this? Same for `< script>` tag too but they have `< script src="//api-cdn.github.io/javascriptfile.js">` for the javascript file

#### My Code

```
// Start github.com script
//// Create Script for Jquery
$(document).ready(function() {
  //// Create the element
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.className = "jquery-1.9.1";
  //// Add script content
  //// Append
  document.head.appendChild(script);
});
// End Script for Jquery
// This is a better way of removeing the stylesheets without messing with the other <link> tags, this reduces error messages in the dev console also
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel=stylesheet]');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
}
// This is a better way of removing the scripts without messing with the other <script> tags, this reduces error messages in the dev console also
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('script');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
}
// Changes the original script linking to assets-cdn.github.com, changes the href & src to # so it wont load any files from assets-cdn.github.com
/// If it loads from that site then the extension will break and the site wont work anymore
//$(document).ready(function() {
//$("script").attr("src", "#");
//$("link").attr("href", "#");
//});
// End Change Script
// Create Element for Script 1
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create the element
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.className = "github-79eedeccbf089da4cd43e8b5299e4ac33d0fa03caa42e936649c23e1b2183ab8";
  // Add script content
  // Append
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});
// End of script 1
// Create Element for Script 2
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create the element
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.className = "frameworks-35b9c541d341309b930b1c790fa1b27a30c7c44ce10c7f8242890e3d83c8adbd";
  // Add script content
  // Append
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});
// End of Script 2
// Create Element for Style 1
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create the element
  var style = document.createElement("style");
  style.className = "frameworks-7a356da712cd13c4e4cfbdc04cf886bb391f84a7e92f9f7b3abf2b1034fea6e9";
  // Add script content
  // Append
  document.head.appendChild(style);
});
// End of Style 1
// Create Element for Style 2
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create the element
  var style = document.createElement("style");
  style.className = "github-85c605289f6f5d0832a168f8ad71a38dff98eed69103be797a45c54c0cca6cac";
  // Add script content
  // Append
  document.head.appendChild(style);
});
// End of Style 2
// Fill Script Jquery-1.9.1
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $(".jquery-1.9.1").html(data);
    }
  });
});
// End Script Jquery-1.9.1
// Fill Script 1
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "//assets-cdn.github.com/assets/github-79eedeccbf089da4cd43e8b5299e4ac33d0fa03caa42e936649c23e1b2183ab8.js",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $(".github-79eedeccbf089da4cd43e8b5299e4ac33d0fa03caa42e936649c23e1b2183ab8").html(data);
    }
  });
});
// End Script 1
// Fill Script 2
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "//assets-cdn.github.com/assets/frameworks-35b9c541d341309b930b1c790fa1b27a30c7c44ce10c7f8242890e3d83c8adbd.js",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $(".frameworks-35b9c541d341309b930b1c790fa1b27a30c7c44ce10c7f8242890e3d83c8adbd").html(data);
    }
  });
});
// End Script 2
// Fill Style 1
$(document).ready(function() {
  //var href = $('link[rel=stylesheet]:nth-of-type(1)').attr('href');
  $.ajax({
    url: "//assets-cdn.github.com/assets/frameworks-7a356da712cd13c4e4cfbdc04cf886bb391f84a7e92f9f7b3abf2b1034fea6e9.css",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $(".frameworks-7a356da712cd13c4e4cfbdc04cf886bb391f84a7e92f9f7b3abf2b1034fea6e9").html(data);
    }
  });
});
// End Style 1
// Fill Style 2
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "inserts the href stylesheet link here",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $(".github-85c605289f6f5d0832a168f8ad71a38dff98eed69103be797a45c54c0cca6cac").html(data);
    }
  });
});
// End Style 2
// End of github.com script
```

Comment: Sorry, I answered without reading your question more thoroughly. Is there only one link and script tag you are interested in or does this need to be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe they give you enough information on those tags for this to be dynamic. It looks like you were close in one of your commented out lines.

If you need to do this for all of their links and scripts tags, you could get all of the elements that you want in a variable, and loop through them. While looping, you would just insert their href values into your code.

Comment: the website the extension injects the scripts into isnt mine i created the extension to fix the new chrome update and the site because with the new version the site wont load correctly and where it shows "inserts the href link here" is where the link is supposed to be placed after the code fetches the stylesheet link and which when the link gets placed it fetches the css/js file its directing to and creates a script/style tag in the website and inserts whatever text is in the file to the tags this extension prevents the cross-origin loading on the site

Comment: theres only 4 tags that I need to do this for I need 1 variable for each, 2 style & 2 Script tags

Comment: ok Nevermind I just figured out how to do it i was right on the commented out line i just needed to add href to the url: section like url: href,